# VBA - Get the day before when a date is specified

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm currently trying to write a piece of code where the user is giving a text box to enter a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy and once that has been specified, I want to get the day before that date.

For example, the user enters 14/12/2018 and I would like VBA to store 13/12/2018 to another variable.

Probably a stupid query, but would be handy to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I figured it out!

Here's what I did in case anyone wants to know:

```
Dim FirstRun as Date
Dim FirstRunBefore as Date

FirstRun = InputBox("Enter date")
FirstRunBefore = Format(DateAdd("d", -1, FirstRun), "dd mmmm yyyy")
```

Comment: You have misused the format function. When something is a date it is actually a whole number e.g. for today it is 43440 shown using what ever your system settings are e.g. '6.12.2018'. If you want to store it in a different format you will have to pass the formatted value to a string variable. To conclude FirstRunBefore is always the same whatever format you apply, it stays the same.

Comment: `DateAdd("d", -1, FirstRun)` could be `FirstRun - 1`. Also you may want to put some error catching in case the input is invalid (e.g. "14.12.2018" if your locale uses "14/12/2018")

Comment: You could use `FirstRun = Application.InputBox("Enter date", Type:=1)` to ensure a number is entered (_1 Jan 2018_ is considered a number as well), or as @iamanigeeit commented - check it's a date `If IsDate(FirstRun) Then....`